# reCAPTCHA is not working in my comments system, How to resolve it?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I am developing one comments system for my website. I need more security, so I am using reCAPTCHA. My reCAPTCHA displayed correct captcha images in my comment form but If I not fill reCAPTCHA inputbox and press a submit button my comments are saved normallyreCAPTCHA is not valued my input. reCAPTCHA is not showing any errors like **you entered wrong value** or **please enter the captcha** like this. Below I attached my all coding please help me to resolve the error. Sorry for my bad English. Thank you!

**index.php**

```
    <?php

// Error reporting:
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

include "connect.php";
include "comment.class.php";


/*
/   Select all the comments and populate the $comments array with objects
*/

$comments = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $comments[] = new Comment($row);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple AJAX Commenting System | Tutorialzine demo</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body>



<h1>Simple AJAX Commenting System</h1>
<h2><a href="http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/simple-ajax-commenting-system/">Go Back to Tutorialzine &raquo;</a></h2>

<div id="main">

<?php

/*
/   Output the comments one by one:
*/

foreach($comments as $c){
    echo $c->markup();
}

?>

<div id="addCommentContainer">
    <p>Add a Comment</p>
    <form id="addCommentForm" method="post" action="">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Your Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

            <label for="email">Your Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

            <label for="url">Website (not required)</label>
            <input type="text" name="url" id="url" />

            <label for="body">Comment Body</label>
            <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
                     <script type="text/javascript">
 var RecaptchaOptions = {
    theme : 'clean'
 };
 </script>
<?php

require_once('recaptchalib.php');

// Get a key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
$publickey = "6LcJeuUSAAAAAH4pKjUer-2meYz_pwhmiH2FLA6R";


echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
?>

            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Connect.php**

```
    <?php

/* Database config */

$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database        = 'com'; 

/* End config */


$link = @mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_select_db($db_database,$link);

?>
```

**comment.class.php**

```
    <?php

class Comment
{
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct($row)
    {
        /*
        /   The constructor
        */

        $this->data = $row;
    }

    public function markup()
    {
        /*
        /   This method outputs the XHTML markup of the comment
        */

        // Setting up an alias, so we don't have to write $this->data every time:
        $d = &$this->data;

        $link_open = '';
        $link_close = '';

        if($d['url']){

            // If the person has entered a URL when adding a comment,
            // define opening and closing hyperlink tags

            $link_open = '<a href="'.$d['url'].'">';
            $link_close =  '</a>';
        }

        // Converting the time to a UNIX timestamp:
        $d['dt'] = strtotime($d['dt']);

        // Needed for the default gravatar image:
        $url = 'http://'.dirname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]).'/img/default_avatar.gif';

        return '
        <p style="align:center;">
            <div class="comment">
                <div class="avatar">
                    '.$link_open.'
                    <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5($d['email']).'?size=50" />
                    '.$link_close.'
                </div>

                <div class="name">'.$link_open.$d['name'].$link_close.'</div>
                <div class="date" title="Added at '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y',$d['dt']).'">'.date('d M Y',$d['dt']).'</div>
                <p>'.$d['body'].'</p>
            </div></p>
        ';
    }

    public static function validate(&$arr)
    {
        /*
        /   This method is used to validate the data sent via AJAX.
        /
        /   It return true/false depending on whether the data is valid, and populates
        /   the $arr array passed as a paremter (notice the ampersand above) with
        /   either the valid input data, or the error messages.
        */

        $errors = array();
        $data   = array();

        // Using the filter_input function introduced in PHP 5.2.0

        if(!($data['email'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)))
        {
            $errors['email'] = 'Please enter a valid Email.';
        }

        if(!($data['url'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'url',FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)))
        {
            // If the URL field was not populated with a valid URL,
            // act as if no URL was entered at all:

            $url = '';
        }

        // Using the filter with a custom callback function:

        if(!($data['body'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'body',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text'))))
        {
            $errors['body'] = 'Please enter a comment body.';
        }

        if(!($data['name'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'name',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text'))))
        {
            $errors['name'] = 'Please enter a name.';
        }

        if(!empty($errors)){

            // If there are errors, copy the $errors array to $arr:

            $arr = $errors;
            return false;
        }

        // If the data is valid, sanitize all the data and copy it to $arr:

        foreach($data as $k=>$v){
            $arr[$k] = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
        }

        // Ensure that the email is lower case:

        $arr['email'] = strtolower(trim($arr['email']));

        return true;

    }

    private static function validate_text($str)
    {
        /*
        /   This method is used internally as a FILTER_CALLBACK
        */

        if(mb_strlen($str,'utf8')<1)
            return false;

        // Encode all html special characters (<, >, ", & .. etc) and convert
        // the new line characters to <br> tags:

        $str = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($str));

        // Remove the new line characters that are left
        $str = str_replace(array(chr(10),chr(13)),'',$str);

        return $str;
    }

}

?>
```

Here is my **style.css** and **script.js** files coding [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jobvirus/bPxyV/)
. I downloaded **recaptchalib.php** from here [Click Here](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label%3aphplib-Latest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

verification doesn't happen automatically ...`recaptcha_check_answer` must be defined somewhere in your code to verify.. see what google has to say about this :

> Server Side (How to test if the user entered the right answer)
>
> **The following code should be placed at the top of the verify.php file**:

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>
```

you can have this code on top of your php file where you are posting your form, in this case your index.php file. more details on https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php?csw=1

Comment: @legndinmaking : Hi, my comment system is jquery based. You see there is no action value like this action="" on my index.php. my comment system is working perfectly without  action value. I searched many websites in every form they have action value like this action="verify.php" .This verify.php is server side coding in my coding which page is the server side coding and where should I add these above coding into my pages. Please explain it friend. Sorry for my bad English. are you under stand my problem?. If you still not understand please copy all coding and run it yourself please for me.

Comment: @Azharuddin it will surely work flawlessly as far as showing stored comment is concerned, but i believe you would be using that Add Comment section to take input from users and store into your database ?

Comment: @legndinmaking: Please tell why my reputation points went to minus value. I am just asking question only not doing anything  bad dude.